Adding shaded SE manually to a lineplot ggplot
I have the following plot, that I am trying to add SE shading bars to.

It is using this dataframe of predicted values from my model.
data.frame(
   x = c(-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8),
   predicted = c(0.68210177774552,0.824971306553031,
                 0.911923452641176,0.957884075392982,0.98037732841837,
                 0.990970636204506,0.995869238009664),
   std.error = c(0.38195580456581,0.22923983122453,
                 0.123053035742282,0.183476660090966,0.328809680207388,
                 0.488362992665536,0.651775655589864),
   conf.low = c(0.503706928219636,0.750465569524191,
                 0.890530388978947,0.940737822137466,0.963272013048915,
                 0.976820374876465,0.985337590318705),
   conf.high = c(0.819367367560485,0.880765628369274,
                 0.929466912178259,0.97022643270505,0.989602181967697,
                 0.996513543605265,0.998845128758168),
   group = as.factor(c("PupilAmp_SMC",
                           "PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC",
                           "PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC")),
   group_col = as.factor(c("PupilAmp_SMC",
                           "PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC",
                           "PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC","PupilAmp_SMC"))
)

I keep trying to use the following code, but I keep getting an error.. not sure how to make the ribbon geom work. Any help would be appreciated!
PupilPEA_SMC <- ggplot(PEAPupilGrob, aes(x= x, predicted))  +
                geom_line(color = "red", size = 2) + 
                ylim(.65,1.0) + 
                labs (y = "Likelihood of Post-Error Accuracy", x = "Single Trial Pupillary Amplitude") +
                geom_ribbon(PEAPupilGrob, aes(ymin=predicted+std.error, ymax= predicted - std.error), alpha=0.1, fill = "red",  
              color = "black", linetype = "dotted") +
                theme_bw() +
                theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
PupilPEA_SMC



There is no need to add the dataset to geom_ribbon, i.e. try with geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=predicted+std.error, ymax= predicted - std.error), ...). But when you add the dataset as the first argument you have to explicitly name it, i.e. do geom_ribbon(data = PEAPupilGrob, aes(ymin=predicted+std.error, ymax= predicted - std.error), ...).

... additionally be aware that your ribbon falls outside of the limits you have set via ylim and hence will be dropped.

omit the call to ylim

Check the arguments to geom_ribbon. You'll see that mapping is the first and data is the second. You are committing a basic error by not naming your arguments, and putting them in the wrong order.

This would work:
ggplot(PEAPupilGrob, aes(x = x, predicted))  +
  geom_line(color = "red", size = 2) + 
  ylim(0.3, 1.7) + 
  labs (y = "Likelihood of Post-Error Accuracy", x = "Single Trial Pupillary Amplitude") +
  geom_ribbon(
    aes(
      ymin = predicted - std.error, 
      ymax = predicted + std.error
    ), 
    alpha = 0.1, 
    fill = "red",  
    color = "black", 
    linetype = "dotted"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))



It will be great if you could post here the output graph also.

Just run the code.

People may be browsing on their phones and not have R.
